# Let PHP enter .htaccess login details

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a test website behind an .htaccess authorisation. This page now offers a web service I'd like to test with a client from another server. Is there a way to let PHP enter the login credentials for .htaccess? I'm looking for something like:

```
$_SERVER['user'] = foo;
$_SERVER['password'] = bar;
```

Many thanks and
best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the apache authentication you can login using:

```
http(s)://user:password@host_ip
```

EDIT

Ok, I just tested it

```
 <?php

 $test = file_get_contents('http://user:password@host_ip/test48.txt');

 echo $test;

 ?>
```

try it.

Comment: Your answer works perfect in the browser but with PHP I apparently can't get a file with file_get_contents(http://user:password@test.website.com/foo.txt) it returns the error HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required

Comment: Is there the possibility this only works with the IP and not the URL? The server I'm trying to test is a Server hosting a Drupal multisite with many pages on the same IP :/

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Read a plain file, a html page or what?

Comment: Accessing a WSDL file for a SOAP Web Service which I can only access with: http://test.website.com/foo/bar/foo/server.php?WSDL (the comment function removes the http)

Comment: ok then if you try ` $test = file_get_contents('http://user:password@test.website.com/foo/bar/foo/server.php?WSDL');` (with http://) does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$localfilename = '/path/to/downloaded/file';
$out = fopen($localfilename, 'wb');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($out);`